# W10 + cygwin + expect

Tags: windows-10, cygwin, expect

I'm using W10  + cygwin.

Big picture is I'm trying to build the toolchain to run the gnu gfortran torture tests, which needs dejagnu, Tcl and expect.

I'm having problems with expect.

After configuring with

```
./configure --build=x86_64-unknown-cygwin   CC=/cygdrive/C/work/usr/local  /bin/gcc  --cache-file=config.cache  &>expect-configure-out.txt
```

which runs fine, producing a 37kb config.log file, the last line of which is  configure: exit 0, so far so good.

Then I run make and make install.

From a mintty command prompt,

```
./expect --version
```

causes an immediate stack dump, which is here:

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at rip=00000000000
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=00000000000D27A0 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=000000006D655AD3
r8 =0000000000000000 r9 =000000006D536EA1 r10=0000000000000000
r11=8101010101010100 r12=000000000011EC30 r13=000000000011EC40
r14=00000000001147C0 r15=000000000011EC40
rbp=0000000000142D40 rsp=00000000FFFFCA28
program=C:\work\usr\local\bin\expect.exe, pid 2016, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
End of stack trace
```

Some questions:

1. With configure, is it better to run the default cygwin c compiler or the latest gnu c compiler?
2. Does the configure option --build=x86_64-unknown-cygwin matter?
3. Does the configure option --prefix=/usr/local/ matter?
4. Should I try recompiling with a large memory model?
5. Does W10 differentiate between executing a program from a mintty command prompt versus a W10 command prompt?
6. Is there any benefit to running autoconf to update the configure file?
7. Any other suggestions that might reduce the number of trial and error permutations to get this running?

Thank you.

Comment: Is running expect on W10 even possible? Checkout    https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/comp.lang.tcl/HRoHzPY6h9w and    https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/875352/a-detailed-description-of-the-data-execution-prevention-dep-feature-in

Comment: Is there some reason you're trying to build expect yourself and not just using the Cygwin package?

Comment: cygwin is awesome and I'm trying to learn more about it by building some of the packages myself.

If you have any tips, I'd appreciate them, thank you.